# Transaction Net Usage Is Too High: 136 > 0

Tags: transfer, resources, net

I am getting this message when trying to transfer EOS from my Ledger nano S:
`Transaction Net Usage Is Too High: 136 > 0`

What is the reason for this error message when trying to do a transaction?

Comment: I am also getting an error like "Transaction Net Usage Is Too High: 184 > 0", but I am trying to unstake all my EOS and remove them from the wallet. HOw do I unstake all?

Comment: @Kim use https://eospowerup.io/free , bloks.io or Anchor-Wallet with Fuel to receive some free CPU and NET to unstake.

Answer (score 1):

This means you don't have any EOS staked to NET bandwidth.

You can stake EOS using the `eosio::delegatebw` action, but it is a chicken and egg situation, because you need some NET bandwidth in order to stake some NET bandwidth.

Therefore I recommend you do it through a service like bloks.io, which offers 5 free transactions per day. You can use one of these transactions in order to make sure you have enough resources staked to your account.